# None output when I run my code

Tags: python, function

I run this code:

```
def fact(i):
    j = 1

    while i >= 1:
        j = i * j
        i -= 1
i = input("input the number: ")
print (fact(i))
```

and see this output:

```
input the number: 6
None
```

Why is my output `None`? What is wrong?

Comment: Why can't you even copy and paste *"None"*? You have no result because *you don't `return` anything.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the **result** of a function. In order for a function to return result, you must use the `return` statement. If you don't return anything, then the the function will **automaticaly** return `None`. I suspect you want your function to return `j` so you need to add `return j` to the end of the function for it to work.

That should work:

```
def fact(i):
    j = 1
    while i >= 1:
        j = i * j
        i -= 1
    return j

i = input("input the number: ")
print (fact(i))
```